# Colors not showing in Chrome the right way?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

I have a this in my CSS styling: `background-color: #0006;` but it works in Firefox but does not work in Chrome. in chrome, it says, "invalid property value" or something like that and it works in firefox. why?

Comment: _or something like that_  . Please provide the exact error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is the hex for #RGBA. It's a newer part of the CSS spec that isn't fully implemented by every browser yet (and certainly not older ones). The version of firefox that you are using has implemented it, whereas the version of chrome you are using clearly hasn't.

The color you've defined is #000 (which is black) and then you've made it semi-transparent by appending the 6. It's advised that you don't use #RGBA yet...

Take a look at the compatibility table here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color_value#Browser_compatibility

Comment: What color do you get? I get "Improper property value".

Comment: A light transparent grey. "improper property value" is the error chrome gives me if you hover over the caution sign in the inspect element